# How to put a pop up box to each cell in a table when mouse over the cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Something like for each in jQuery..

```
$('#id').each( function( index ) {
   $(this).addClass('item-' + index);
});
```

Comment: $('#id') won't work since id's should be only declared once. you'll definitly need a class or general element here. Also I cannot understand haw a class with an upcounting name will help you to create a popup box - what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the same class to all the cells in a table use this:

```
$('#tableId td').each( function( index ) {
   $(this).addClass('classname');
});
```

This way you will iterate over all the td childrens of the table with the #tableID.

And you can add a tooltip with custom content using jqueryui this way:

```
$('#tableId td').each( function( index ) {
    $(this).tooltip({
        content: function() {
            var contentHTML = ""; //Text or html you want to show in the tooltip
            return contentHTML;     
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `id` should be unique in same document, so the simplest way to adapt your code is to change every `id='id'` in your code by generale class called `id` it will be `class='id'`, then use `$('.id')` instead :

```
$('.id').each( function( index ) {
    $(this).addClass('item-' + index);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a popup on mouseover of each element in a table try with the code below,

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Aryan</td>
<td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Dia</td>
<td>22</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('mouseover', 'th,td', function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var html = '<div class="popup">' + $(this).text() + '</div>';
    $('.popup').remove();
    $(html).insertBefore('table');
    $('.popup').css({ 'top': offset.top, 'left': offset.left }).fadeIn();
});
```

});

CSS:

```
table{border-collapse:collapse}
th,td{padding:10px}
.popup{display:none;position:absolute;background:#ccc;border-radius:6px;padding:8px;}
```

This sample code creates a popup of the text on which you hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/zmd2ct54/

Answer (score 2):

thank you all...
I used this and it worked...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.results-info-hover').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.popover({
            container: 'body',
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'bottom',
            html: true,
            content: $this.find('.results-info').html(),

        });
        });
    });
```